# Struts json result includeProperties regex not working with root present

Tags: struts2, struts2-json-plugin

This question has been asked several times around struts community, the scenario is simple :If you specify

```
<param name="root">
myLists               
</param>
```

in  json result definition, the includeProperties won't work if I specify some regEx like this one:

```
 <param name="includeProperties">
   .*\.movieId,
    .*\.filmName
  </param>
```

the regex is proposed in [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/issues/detail?id=17#c14),plain field name won't work either.

if I remove root definition ,I can get the JSON ok but with additional JSON traversing which is undesiralbe.

So, is there any solution fix this problem? thx.

Answer (score 3):

```
<param name="includeProperties">
 \[\d+\]\.movieId,
 \[\d+\]\.filmName
</param>
```

should do the trick.

Raising the log level to DEBUG for org.apache.struts2.json helped me clarifying this one.